# Django Postgres database records reordering

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

For some reason every time I save a record to my postgres (it's on heroku) database from Django, that record is moved to the end of the database.

For example, if I have 3 records:

> record1
>
> record2
>
> record3

And I update record 1, they become ordered like this:

> record2
>
> record3
>
> record1

This is making it tough for my website to navigate through a set of pages in the right order. Anybody know how to stop these records from moving around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't. SQL databases can and do change the order of records as needed to ensure efficiency and speed.

If you always want to display records in a certain order, you need to add the ordering yourself. You could do something like have a "created_at" column in which you store a timestamp when the record is created, and then sort by that column when you retrieve the records, using `order_by`.

Comment: The time stamp is a great idea, thanks! I'll try implementing something like that.

Comment: I tried adding a new column but adding a new field to my model. I tried to do a migration but heroku won't detect a change in my model, any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Sometimes Heroku won't run the migration for you, you have to do it yourself from the CLI. But that's a different question from this one. :)

Comment: Right you are. Thanks for the help!